# Same tag for multiple Visual Studio repositories

Tags: git

I have multiple Visual Studio solutions, each one of them has its own Git repository allowing me to work with Team Explorer for all Git operations I need (merging, branching, commit...)

I want to be able to  create the same tag at the same moment for all the repositories. I thought about creating a parent git repository that will hold all the sub-repositories so I can tag the parent repo but then I don't know how the child repos will be handled. I also red about Git submodules but I don't think that is the correct way to do it since my sub-repositories are fully tied together and not used in any other project. Submodules seems to be relevant when using a 3rd party libraries but it's not the case here.

What is the correct way to go in these kind of cases?

Comment: Why do all of the tags have to be created "at the same moment"?  You could script out adding the tag to the most recent commit (say, on the master branch) of each repository.